# What does the “5D’s” mean in Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D’s?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

*Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D’s* is the third incarnation of the Yu-Gi-Oh! franchise. Having watched the first season (dub), I still have no clue what the 5D’s in the title is supposed to mean.

Was it just something that sounds cool in Japanese? Or is there actually meaning to it?

Answer (score 2):

The 5D's is meant to represent the legendary **5 D**ragons ([Signer Dragons](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Signer_Dragon)) that the protagonists ([Signers](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Signer)) use in order to fight the antagonists ([Dark Signers](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Signer)).

These dragons are:

1. Stardust Dragon
2. Red Dragon Archfiend
3. Black Rose Dragon
4. Ancient Fairy Dragon
5. Black-Winged Dragon

> This was what the initial story made to believe anyway, because later on in the series, there is one more protagonist who awakens as a Signer and obtains a Signer Dragon; Leo obtains his after a duel where his life was on the line along with his sister Luna and Jack (both of whom were originally confirmed Signers). The sixth dragon is named Life Stream Dragon

Comment: [Fun fact](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_5D%27s#Title_misinterpretation): While "5 Dragons" is the correct definition, 4Kids mislabeled it as "5 Duel Scoop"